# What is the difference between springcloud-stream and springcloud-bus？

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-bus

What are the differences between them?

Is `springcloud-stream` one of the instantiations of `springcloud-bus`?
As I know, both of them concern about MQ.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Cloud Bus is built on top of Spring Cloud Stream.

It's a Spring Cloud Stream application.